# Is this method to calculate gcd of two polynomials correct?

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

I have the following two polynomials:
$$a(x) = x^3+4x^2+x-6,b(x) = x^5-6x+5$$

We observe that $a(x) = (x-1)(x+2)(x+3).$ We observe that $b(1)=0$ and $b(-2),b(-3)$ are not equal to $0.$ Thus $\gcd(a,b) = x-1.$

Comment: It's correct. This method works in any U.F.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. More generally: if you have two polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, if$$\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}=\{\text{roots of }p(x)\}\cup\{\text{roots of }q(x)\},$$and if $\alpha_1,\beta_1,\ldots,\alpha_k,\beta_k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ are such that$$p(x)=(x-a_1)^{\alpha_1}\cdots(x-a_k)^{\alpha_k}\text{ and }q(x)=(x-a_1)^{\beta_1}\cdots(x-a_k)^{\beta_k},$$then$$\gcd\bigl(p(x),q(x)\bigr)=(x-a_1)^{\min\{\alpha_1,\beta_1\}}\cdots(x-a_k)^{\min\{\alpha_k,\beta_k\}}.$$In your case, your polynomials have one and only one common root, which is a simple root of one of them.

Answer (score 1):

$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 6 x  + 5 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 6 x  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 4 x  + 15 \right) } +  \left(   - 50 x^{2}  - 45 x  + 95 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right)  =  \left(   - 50 x^{2}  - 45 x  + 95 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 10 x  - 31 }{ 500 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 11 x  - 11 }{ 100 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   - 50 x^{2}  - 45 x  + 95 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 11 x  - 11 }{ 100 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 5000 x  - 9500 }{ 11 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 4 x  + 15 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{2}  - 4 x  + 15 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 10 x  - 31 }{ 500 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 10 x^{3}  + 9 x^{2}  - 26 x  + 35 }{ 500 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 10 x  - 31 }{ 500 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 5000 x  - 9500 }{ 11 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 100 x^{4}  + 100 x^{3}  + 100 x^{2}  + 100 x  - 500 }{ 11 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 100 x^{2}  + 500 x  + 600 }{ 11 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  +  x  - 5 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 10 x  - 31 }{ 55 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  + 5 x  + 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 10 x^{3}  + 9 x^{2}  - 26 x  + 35 }{ 55 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  - 6 x  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  +  x  - 5 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 5 x  + 6 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  - 6 x  + 5 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 10 x  - 31 }{ 55 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 10 x^{3}  + 9 x^{2}  - 26 x  + 35 }{ 55 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x  + 1 \right)  $$

.........