# Finding the gcd of polynomials $p,q$ and writing $\gcd(p,q)=d_1(x)p+d_2(x)q$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I'm given $p(x)=x^3+4x^2+x-6, q(x)=x^5-6x+5$. I'm asked for the GCD in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$; which I know to be $x-1$ by factoring. However; writing $x-1$ as a combination of p and q (that is; finding $d_1(x),d_2(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ s.t. $qd_1(x)+pd_2(x)=x-1$)seems to require Euclid algorithm (this is how I would proceed if these where say, integers). This gets impossibly messy; I've tried 3 times now and none of my solutions checked out. Is there some more sophisticated trick or method I'm missing here?

Comment: You can factor the first polynomial as $(x-1)(x+2)(x+3)$, and you can just check it manually.

Comment: yes, this is true, the challge is writing x-1 as a linear combination of p and q...

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830421/is-this-method-to-calculate-gcd-of-two-polynomials-correct

Comment: It is the exact same question asked earlier on the site.

Comment: To keep the degrees low you could do write $1$ as a linear combination of $p/(x-1)$ and $q/(x-1)$, and then multiply both sides by $x-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euclidean algorithm works perfectly fine. Two polynomial long divisions yield:
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1\times&(x^5-6x+5)&-&(x^2-4x+15)\times&(x^3+4x^2+x-6)&=&-50x^2-45x+95\\
50\times&(x^3+4x^2+x-6)&-&(-x-\tfrac{31}{10})\times&(-50x^2-45x+95)&=&\tfrac{11}{2}(x-1).\\
\end{array}
Substituting back then yields
$$x-1=\frac{10x+31}{55}q+\frac{-10x^3+9x^2-26x+35}{55}p.$$